# Tricky limits question - If $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow(0,0)} \ f(0,y)=0$ then $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow(0,0)} \ f(x,y)=0$. True or False?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am asked the following question:

> If $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow(0,0)} \ f(0,y)=0$ then $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow(0,0)} \ f(x,y)=0$

The textbook contains no answer so I would like to check my reasoning on this forum.

**Answer**

Let's say the question was actually this one:

> If $\displaystyle \lim_{(0,y) \rightarrow(0,0)} \ f(x,y)=0$ then $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow(0,0)} \ f(x,y)=0$

This, for me, is absolutely incorrect: just because we took one path ($x=0$) and finding a specific value for the limit **on that path**, doesn't allow us to generalize for the whole limit.

**Yes, I know, that's not the original question. And that's where I struggle.**

For the original question, I would say it's false but then that would be me just guessing. How should I view the original question?

Comment: @zhw. you mean the description of the exercise on the textbook is wrong? (wouldn't be the first time that happens though)

Comment: bru1987.Related:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2678386/evaluate-lim-x-y-to-0-0-fracx-sin-yxy/2678465.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider as counterexample

$$f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$$

then

- $f(0,y)=0$
- $f(t,t)=\frac12$

Comment: mmm I see, that would lead us to $0$ (the exercises' reasoning) but also $\frac{1}{2}$ if we take $x=y$, so the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. Thank you, that was very helpful.

Comment: In this case $\displaystyle \lim_{y \rightarrow 0} \ f(0,y)=0$ exist but $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow(0,0)} \ f(x,y)$ does not.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* the same question.  Your notation is a bit unusual, perhaps, but what you say is right.  In either event, $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$ along the $x-$axis, which doesn't guarantee the existence of the limit.